# south & mysql problem

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south

can somebody help me out on this:
I have installed recently south to use it updating changes in my django-based project on the production server (Appache 2.0, MySql 5.0, python 2.5, Mysqldb for python, django 1.3, and south 0.7.3). 
After converting my app named signature to south, which was done successfully, the command`manage migrate signature` it prints the following output:

```
C:\python projects\suivireal>manage.py migrate signature

Running migrations for signature:
- Migrating forwards to 0002_auto__del_field_agent_titre_en__add_field_agent_ni

veau__add_field_agen.

> signature:0002_auto__del_field_agent_titre_en__add_field_agent_niveau__add_fi

eld_agen

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python projects\suivireal\manage.py", line 14, in <module>

    execute_manager(settings)

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line

438, in execute_manager

    utility.execute()

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line

379, in execute

    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191,

in run_from_argv

    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 220,

in execute

    output = self.handle(*args, **options)

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\management\comma

nds\migrate.py", line 102, in handle

    delete_ghosts = delete_ghosts,

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\migration\__init

__.py", line 202, in migrate_app

    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\migration\migrat

ors.py", line 215, in migrate_many

    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, datab

ase)

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\migration\migrat

ors.py", line 284, in migrate_many

    result = self.migrate(migration, database)

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\migration\migrat

ors.py", line 121, in migrate

    result = self.run(migration)

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\migration\migrat

ors.py", line 94, in run

    dry_run.run_migration(migration)

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\migration\migrat

ors.py", line 172, in run_migration

    self._run_migration(migration)

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\migration\migrat

ors.py", line 162, in _run_migration

    raise exceptions.FailedDryRun(migration, sys.exc_info())

south.exceptions.FailedDryRun:  ! Error found during dry run of '0002_auto__del_

field_agent_titre_en__add_field_agent_niveau__add_field_agen'! Aborting.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\migration\migrat

ors.py", line 159, in _run_migration

    migration_function()

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\migration\migrat

ors.py", line 56, in <lambda>

    return (lambda: direction(orm))

File "C:\python projects\suivireal\..\suivireal\signature\migrations\0002_auto

__del_field_agent_titre_en__add_field_agent_niveau__add_field_agen.py", line 12,

in forwards

    db.delete_column('signature_agent', 'titre_en')

File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\South-0.7-py2.6.egg\south\db\mysql.py", li

ne 90, in delete_column

    result = cursor.execute(get_fkeyname_query % (db_name, table_name, name))

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 34, in e

xecute

    return self.cursor.execute(sql,     params)

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 86

, in execute

    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 176, in execute

    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_

check     warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)

Warning: Table 'chold.signupsetup' doesn't exist
```

I googled to see the problem whether it is related to mysql but I couldn't a find a way out.

Comment: Please, explain what did you do before typing "migrate signature".

Comment: starting with "convert_to_south" then I did some changes in the model where I added a field and changed a field name. After that, when I executed schemamigrate option, it askes me to fill out the default value field for those fields, I did, it worked fine. After that, I execute migrate based on its recomandation, it sort the error explained above.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that there is a missing table in your database called "chold.signupsetup".

You should check that that this table exists, and if not create it. The usual way of creating tables for django apps is to run syncdb:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

Then try running the migration again.

Comment: I am sure the did the syncdb before even start to migrate. I did it as you said, the same problem appears. notice, the error report, it is in somehow generated from MYsqldb driver. I couldn't find why?